# Pydantic object has no attribute '__fields_set__' error

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm working with FastAPI to create a really simple dummy API. For it I was playing around with enums to define the require body for a post request and simulating a DB call from the API method to a dummy method.

To have the proper body request on my endpoint, Im using Pydantic's BaseModel on the class definition but for some reason I get this error

```
File "pydantic/main.py", line 406, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__setattr__ 
AttributeError: 'MagicItem' object has no attribute '__fields_set__'
```

I'm not sure what's the problem, here is my code that generate all this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm kinda lost right now cuz I don't see the error in such a simple code.

Comment: Can you replace screenshots of your code with actual code blocks? This will allow better accessibility for those visiting the site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You basically completely discarded the Pydantic `BaseModel.__init__` method on your `MagicItem`. Generally speaking, if you absolutely have to override the Base Model's init-method (and in your case, you **don't**), you should at least call it inside your own like this:

```py
super().__init__(...)
```

Pydantic does a whole lot of magic in the init-method. One of those things being the setting of the `__fields_set__` attribute. That is why you are getting that error.

I suggest just completely removing your custom `__init__` method.

One of the main benefits of using Pydantic models is that you **don't** have to worry about writing boilerplate like this. Check out their [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#basic-model-usage), it is really good in my opinion.

**PS:**

If you *insist* because you want to be able to initialize your `MagicItem` with *positional* arguments, you could just do this:

```py
class MagicItem(BaseModel):
    name: str
    damage: Damage

    def __init__(self, name: str, damage: Damage) -> None:
        super().__init__(name=name, damage=damage)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not a full-fledged solution, but if you are having a similar problem and [@daniil-fajnberg's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73664830/pydantic-object-has-no-attribute-fields-set-error#answer-73664882) doesn't fix it for you, **make sure that you are not accessing the `self` object before calling `super()`**

---

This will fail:

```py
class MagicItem(BaseModel):
    name: str
    damage: Damage
    foo: Any # <---- an extra property

    def __init__(self, name: str, damage: Damage, foo: Any) -> None:
        self.foo = foo # <---- x before super()!
        super().__init__(name=name, damage=damage)
```

Whereas this is what worked for me:

```py
class MagicItem(BaseModel):
    name: str
    damage: Damage
    foo: Any # <---- an extra property

    def __init__(self, name: str, damage: Damage, foo: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(name=name, damage=damage)
        self.foo = foo # <---- ✓ after super()!
```